# Null Safety on IF comparison in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

I have a question about how Kotlin manages `NULL` safety on comparison.
I have this code:

```
imageFile.addListener { _ , oldValue : File?, newValue : File? ->
    run{
        if(oldValue?.absolutePath != newValue?.absolutePath) loadFile()
    }
}
```

**It works fine**, however if I change it to

```
imageFile.addListener { _ , oldValue : File?, newValue : File? ->
    run{
        if(oldValue!!.absolutePath != newValue?.absolutePath) loadFile()
    }
}
```

It throws a `NullPointerException` and that's obvious, because when the application starts `oldValue` is `NULL`.

How Kotlin manages this comparison the first time?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) which avoid `NullPointerException`:

> option is the safe call operator, written `?.`
>
> **returns null if any of the properties in it is null**.

Second option [not-null assertion operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#the--operator) throws exception

> **The !! Operator**
>
> the not-null assertion operator (!!) converts any value to a non-null type and **throws an exception if the value is null**

Comment: Yes, that's true. However, I don't understand how the two values can compare if `absolutePath` cannot be obtained on `oldValue` (because it's `NULL`). Thank you.

Comment: If `oldValue` is null, then `oldValue?.absolutePath` is null. Then you just compare null with `newValue?.absolutePath`.

Comment: @Raffaele you are comparing null value as ardenit mention

Comment: OK! I got it. The values are different because `oldValue?.absolutePath` is evaluated in `NULL` and compared with a non-`NULL` value. Thank you!